# I have a problem in Foundation Slope and steel work?

Tags: civil-engineering

How can we find the foundation slop? Is there any equation kindly tell me?

[image]

Comment: This is section 4-4.  the source drawing or another drawing may contain the missing horizontal distance of the sloped portion.  The reason the horizontal distance may be missing is the pit depth may vary.  I can't really read the note.  Supplying a horizontal distance would fix it and you would wind up with a vary slope as a result which should be avoided.  However usually in structural engineer we tend to design to standard slopes and in my neck of the woods it would be rations such as 1:1, 2:1, 1:4, 12:1.  In you case your slope looks like 45degree or 1:1.

Comment: The drawing has a scale. You can trust that the scale is correct and then use it to find any dimension that you want.

Comment: There should be a slope indicator either on this drawing or a dimensional drawing if reinforcing and dimension are separated for clarity.  There also may be a typical drawing which indicates the slope.  Read the drawings general notes if there are any.  Also read the contract specification as the information may be located there as well.  Worst case scenario, submit a Request for Information to the design engineer.

Comment: @hazzey  usually on drawing I work with there is a not that states "Do not scale drawings".  Having said that I do agree if you are out of options.

Comment: @ForwardEd I agree. I never put scales on my structural drawings. If it isn't specifically dimensioned, it should not be figured out with a scale.

Answer (score 1):

This is a "reinforcing steel detail drawing" that does not contain all the dimensions necessary for calculating the slope. Go to the general plan set, find the missing (horizontal) dimensions from the detail drawing for the concrete, and work out the dimension "D". The slope is "$V:H = C:D$".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The angle can be determined by noting that it is parallel to the "Compact Soil hatch pattern", 45 degrees.

Also if you have the original file, not the PDF, you can use the common commands such as The MEASUREGEOM command that provides several options to report distances, angles, radius values, and several other measurements, Autodesk.
Alternatively, you can read the angle directly from the print using a protractor.

Howevver be advised that the slope shown on a detail could be defferent than the actuall slope shown on the sections and in case of conflict priority is plans and sections.